# Select all children except first one of element

Tags: jquery, html, css, drupal-7, colorbox

I need to select all children of an element except the first one. I am working with drupal and colorbox module, and I can't add unique classes or an ID to the first element alone.

```
<span> 
<span> 
<a> </a> <a> <img> </a>
<a> <img> </a>
<a> <img> </a>
</span> 
</span>
```

I have that structure and
can have more `<a> <img> </a>` but you get the idea.

In short. I need to select all the image tags inside the a tags `<a> <img> </a>` so I can apply a CSS rule to them, without affecting the first `<a>` tag. Maybe there's a Jquery solution to this? Thank you

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You have 2 `a`'s in the first link

Comment: does my answer work with the new markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not(:first-child)` to exclude the first link

```css
.myClass img {
  content: url('http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png');
}

.myClass a:not(:first-child) img {
  content: url('http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz3.png');
}
```

```html
<span> 
<span class="myClass"> 
<a> <img> </a>
<a> <img> </a>
<a> <img> </a>
</span> 
</span>
```

It's basically the same thing in jquery.

```js
$('a:not(:first-child)').css('background','red');
```

```css
a {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> 
<span> 
<a> <img> </a>
<a> <img> </a>
<a> <img> </a>
</span> 
</span>
```

Comment: let's assume this is the second span <span class="myClass "> </span> This should be the CSS? 
.myClass a:not(first-child){ display:inline;}

Comment: I've tried it, and it's working for the <a> tag but I need to target the <img> inside the <a> as working on the <a> isn't giving any results.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this  `$("span>a").not(":eq(0)")`

```js
$("span>a").not(":eq(0)").css('background','red');
```

```css
.myClass a {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
}
.myClass a:not(:first-child) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> 
<span> 
<a> dsada</a> <a> <img> </a>
<a>dsada <img> </a>
<a> dsada<img> </a>
</span> 
</span>
```

Comment: your welcome:) you can also use jquery .not(":eq(0)") function